# How did I end-up having a 78-cp Weedle and a 62-cp Kakuna (an evolved Weedle)?

Tags: pokemon-go

An evolved Pokemon *should* be stronger than their original form.
But, I've got a 78-cp Weedle and a 62-cp Kakuna.

This is what probably happened?

- I evolved a very weak Weedle into a Kakuna.
- I just captured a very strong Weedle.

pathway forward:
Reap the Kakuna for a candy and evolve the strong Weedle into another Kakuna? And I get 500 XP for my troubles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your level will grow fast in the beginning. And when your level grows, so wil the CP of the pokemon you encounter. And yes, you will find pokemon with higher cp than their evolved versions. Take the candy and evolve a new one :) the XP is usefull.